# Cannot visit SSRS from remote machine

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I installed sqlserver 2012 with SSRS report on sqlserver machine A. Then I installed our product on machine A and another machine B, they both use sqlserver and ssrs on A.

But when I run ssrs report from our product on machine A and B, the result were different. A could run SSRS report successfully. But B couldn't and there was an error "Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ItemNotFoundException: The item '/xxx' cannot be found."
So this means visiting SSRS from local machine is OK, but from remote machine is not.

I googled a lot about this topic, but didn't get my answer.

I installed SQL-server on several machines, only one of them worked fine. I didn't get why.

Does anyone know what might be the cause? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely one of two things:

- You have an invalid shared dataset or datasource reference.  The item could be missing entirely, be out of date, or have an invalid definition.  Go into the Report Properties and verify that all of its datasets are properly linked.  Go into each dataset definition and verify that they are linked to a datasource.  Go into each datasource and verify that it's able to connect.
- The URL that you used to access the report contained a specific execution ID, which has either long since expired on the server, or never even existed if you tried re-using a copy/pasted link between sites and only changing the server name.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will go back to check my environment.